Sum of $N$ random phases: $\mathbb E \left( \sum_{m=1}^N e^{i(\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_m)} \right)$
Let $\theta_1,\ldots, \theta_N$ be i.i.d. normal random variables $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then, how can we evaluate (exactly or approximately)
$$I = \mathbb E \left(\sum_{m=1}^N e^{i(\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_m)} \right),$$
namely, the sum of $N$ random phases. I am interested in the regime of $N\gg 1$ and small phase variation $\sigma \ll 1$. Also, $\theta_i$ is assumed to obey the normal distribution for concreteness, but one may replace this to other distributions if that makes the problem easier.
My guess is that $I\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$, since the accumulated phase $\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_m$ would be not small as long as $m\gtrsim 1/\sigma$, giving rise to cancellation. But can we obtain a more precise behavior in the above regime?

By $N$ random phases, I assume you mean $N$ is random. If you assume $N$ is independent of the $\theta$'s, and $N$ is positive integer valued, then conditon on $N$.
$\theta_{1}+...+\theta_{k}\sim N(0,k\sigma^{2})$ and the characteristic function of a $N(\mu,a^{2})$ random variable is $e^{it\mu-t^{2}a^{2}/2}$. Thus,
$E(\sum_{m=1}^{N}e^{i(\theta_{1}+...+\theta_{m})})=E(E(\sum_{m=1}^{N}e^{i(\theta_{1}+...+\theta_{m})})|N)=E(\sum_{m=1}^{N}e^{-m\sigma^{2}/2})$
Again, condition on $N$ to get that the above is
$$e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}E\bigg(\frac{1-e^{-N\sigma^{2}/2}}{1-e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}\bigg)=\frac{e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}{1-e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}(1-\phi_{N}(-\sigma^{2}/2))$$
Where $\phi_{N}(t)=e^{tN}$ denotes the Moment Generating Function of $N$.
If you did not mean $N$ to be random, then it is even better.
You just have $\phi_{N}(-\sigma^{2}/2)=e^{-N\sigma^{2}/2}$ which goes to $0$ as $N\to\infty$ and you get
$$\frac{e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}{1-e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}$$
Otherwise directly see that for $N$ non-random,$$E(\sum_{m=1}^{N}e^{i(\theta_{1}+...+\theta_{m})})=\sum_{m=1}^{N}e^{-m\sigma^{2}/2}=e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}\frac{1-e^{-N\sigma^{2}/2}}{1-e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}\xrightarrow{N\to\infty}\frac{e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}{1-e^{-\sigma^{2}/2}}$$

I suspect $N$ is fixed (until you change it to have $N \to \infty$) so the second half of your answer

It might be of interest the case where both $N \to \infty$ and $\sigma \to 0$
